# Problems with return value of boolean methods

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this function to show an AlertDialog when taping on marker:

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Geo.this);
    String[] columns_descri = new String[] {COL_DESCRI};
    Cursor cur = db.query(true, TABLE_COORD, columns_descri,null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.moveToPosition(index-1)) {
    String description = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DESCRI));
    dialog.setTitle("Info.");
    dialog.setMessage(description); 
    dialog.show();
    }
    db.close();
    return true;     }
```

And this method to retrieve any tapped touch on map:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView maMap) 
    {   
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
            GeoPoint p = maMap.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                            
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is when `onTouchEvent` returns TRUE i can't control the map, move it, or show the AlertDialog when taping on a marker. When it's false, i re-take control of the map, but  the toast displays many time(5 or 6 times).
What could be the source of this weird problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTouchEvent is called on EACH touch event.
Press, drag (many events), release.
Therefore your toast is showing a lot.
return true only inside your if clause and return false otherwise.
That should solve it.

Comment: I maked it but i can't get the tap of markers working. But at least i have the control of the map.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean value of the onTap and onTouch events represent whether the action was fully handled or not.  If you return true, the OS will stop cascading to other views (hence why you lose control of the map). When you return false, the OS will look for other methods that can handle the touch event.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So any ideas of how solving the problem ?

Comment: Are both of these on the same mapview?  Would you be able to put the code on `onTouchEvent()` into an `onKeyUp()` instead?  I haven't tested whether that would work, but I'm think an tap on the map would trigger both only once which sounds like what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView maMap) 
    {   
        //---when user lifts his finger---
        boolean result = false;
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
            GeoPoint p = maMap.getProjection().fromPixels(
                (int) event.getX(),
                (int) event.getY());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                    p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result true;
        }                            
        //return (result | super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I tested this code, i can take control of the map, but when i tap on a marker it doesn't shows an AlertDialog.

Comment: Do you mean result true or return true? :\ (surely RETURN)